# What is mdflagwriter and why does it eat up so much RAM?

Tags: macos, spotlight

On my Mavericks 10.9.4 instance of `mdflagwriter` eats up 2.18G of RAM. I know that it's somehow related to Spotlight, but what is it exactly and why is it so RAM-hungry?

Comment: I got this process running after I downloaded Raw Images of Mars from NASA site. Every time I use this images to a closest magnification or if I mark it with arrow, I can see how much difference it makes in my CPU monitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdflagwriter` is part of Spotlight's indexing. There seems to be a bug present for some people where mdflagwriter uses a considerable amount of RAM, but no canonical fix, apart from reinstalling OS X, or for some people reindexing with `sudo mdutil -E /`.

Comment: Thanks. Well, reinstalling is not an option, luckily I have 32G RAM, so I'll just leave it at what it is, will try to reindex stuff as well.